# Reset password link asks user to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise for authentication. When forgot password is called it asks for mail address and it sends a link to the mail, but when I click on the link in the mail I get:

> > You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.

How can I change this so that when clicking on the link it asks for a new password?

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my routes as follows:

```
devise_for :users do
  resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you changed controller that manages passwords (`Devise::PasswordsController` by default) and added `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in, do you? Then you need to remove the filter.

If not, can you describe customizations you done?

**UPDATE:** It's because of conflicting routes of your resources and Devise. Here [on a devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) you can find solution.

Comment: I have changed my routes to "devise_for :users do
      resources :users, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
        end"

Comment: I can't write comments under Rubyman's answer, but "Couldn't find User with id=password" is displayed because of your :users resources. It tries invoke your "users#show" action. [Here on a devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) you can find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => ['password_change_action']
```

to the controller of the `password_change` action.

Comment: It displays "Couldn't find User with id=password"